# kql query show rgname and subscription

Tags: azure, kql

How can we print subscriptionname,resousce groupname using kql query in azure log analytics
its showing vmname but need these details. this is kql query in azure log analytics

```
let start_time=startofday(datetime("2019-03-01 00:00:00 AM"));
let end_time=endofday(datetime("2019-03-31 11:59:59 PM"));
Heartbeat
| where TimeGenerated > start_time and TimeGenerated < end_time
| summarize heartbeat_per_hour=count() by bin_at(TimeGenerated, 1h, start_time), Computer
| extend available_per_hour=iff(heartbeat_per_hour>0, true, false)
| summarize total_available_hours=countif(available_per_hour==true) by Computer 
| extend total_number_of_buckets=round((end_time-start_time)/1h)
| extend availability_rate=total_available_hours*100/total_number_of_buckets
```

Comment: You can pull the subscriptionId, Resource Group Name using Heartbeat. To pull the specific machine subscriptionId and resource group you need to change the line 5 and 7 (summarize statements as below) 
Line 5 : `summarize heartbeat_per_hour=count() by bin_at(TimeGenerated, 1h, start_time), Computer,SubscriptionId,ResourceGroup` and line 7 : `summarize total_available_hours=countif(available_per_hour==true) by Computer,SubscriptionId,ResourceGroup`

Comment: Refer to this documentation, to know list of columns in HeartBeat table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/heartbeat#columns

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @VenkateshDodda for pointing towards the right direction. After making few changes, I ran below query with the given time stamp, and it worked as expected.

```bash
let starttime=startofday(datetime("2020-03-01 00:00:00 AM"));
let endtime=endofday(datetime("2023-06-05 11:59:59 PM"));
Heartbeat
| where TimeGenerated > starttime and TimeGenerated < endtime
| summarize heartbeat_per_hour=count() by bin_at(TimeGenerated, 1h, starttime), Computer,ResourceGroup,SubscriptionId
| extend available_per_hour=iff(heartbeat_per_hour>0, true, false)
| summarize total_avail_hours=countif(available_per_hour==true) by Computer,ResourceGroup,SubscriptionId
| extend total_number_of_buckets=round((endtime-starttime)/1h)
| extend availability_rate=total_avail_hours*100/total_number_of_buckets
```

[image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/heartbeat) for more relevant information.